# Show that an automorphism is not inner

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Lets say I have an automorphism given by $\phi(A)=A^{-T}$ in the group $GL_2(F)$, I need to show that this isnt an inner automorphism. How exactly do I do that? Can I just chose an $A \in GL_2(F)$ and $B \in GL_2(F)$ and show that $A^{-T}$ isnt the same as $BA^{-T}B^{-1}$? Which holds for pretty much any matrices $A$ and $B$.

Next, if we restrict $\phi$ to only include matrices in $SL_2(F)$, then the automorphism is inner? I have no clue about this question, sorry ..

Any hints are welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you would need to show that the equality does not hold for *any* choice of $B$.

Comment: What do you means for $A^{-T}$?

Comment: The inverse of the transpose, or the transpose of the inverse (if you like it the otherway around)

Comment: The hint is in the question : $SL_2(F) = $ restriction of $GL_2(F)$ to $\det(A) = \pm 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\det(BAB^{-1})=\det A$ and $\det A^{-T}=\frac1{\det A}$

Comment: Oh, I feel so silly now .. Thank you good sir!

Comment: This argument  doesn't work when $|F|=2$.